# Adding the data of all previous items to the current item in a ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

All I want is to add the amount of all previous records to the current record's amount in the second column as shown below.
The **[index-1]** adds only the previous record's amount, I want addition of **ALL** previous records amount to current record amount. What should I do?

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">

         <td><span ng-if="record.status == 'unsettle' ">{{record.created_on}}</span></td>
         <td><span ng-if="record.status == 'unsettle' ">{{record.amount+records[$index-1].amount}}</span></td>

</tr>
```

Comment: Perhaps this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31121944/angularjs-ng-repeat-running-total-based-on-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this

```
<tr ng-repeat="record in records">

     <td><span ng-if="record.status == 'unsettle' ">{{record.created_on}}</span></td>
     <td><span ng-init="record.sum=record.amount+records[$index-1].sum" ng-if="record.status == 'unsettle' ">{{record.sum}}</span></td>
```

Comment: Perfect answer! But the first index still is not being added to the sum. Can't figure out the reason as I'm actually new to this. Still, thanks a lot, sir.